# How to add a member on list email with first name and last name in mailchimp?

Tags: php, mailchimp

i successfully able to add a member's email address in mailchimp list .. but don't able to add that member's first name , last name , phone ... etc..
how can i do that ?

```
<?php
$email = 'Email___';
$list_id = 'List_Id___';
$api_key = 'API_KEY';

$data_center = substr($api_key, strpos($api_key, '-')+1);

$url = 'https://'. $data_center .'.api.mailchimp.com/3.0/lists/'. $list_id .'/members';

$json = json_encode([
    'email_address' => $email,
    'status'        => 'subscribed', 
]);

$ch = curl_init($url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERPWD, 'user:' . $api_key);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, ['Content-Type: application/json']);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 10);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $json);
$result = curl_exec($ch);
$status_code = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);
curl_close($ch);
echo $status_code;
echo "<pre>";
print_r(json_decode($result));
echo "</pre>";
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

````
<?php
$email = 'Email___';
$list_id = 'List_Id___';
$api_key = 'API_KEY';

$data_center = substr($api_key, strpos($api_key, '-')+1);

$url = 'https://'. $data_center .'.api.mailchimp.com/3.0/lists/'. $list_id .'/members';

$json = json_encode([
    'email_address' => $email,
    'status'        => 'subscribed', 
'merge_fields' =>
        [
            'FNAME' => 'Jabir',
            'LNAME' => 'Hasan',

        ]
]);

$ch = curl_init($url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERPWD, 'user:' . $api_key);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, ['Content-Type: application/json']);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 10);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $json);
$result = curl_exec($ch);
$status_code = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);
curl_close($ch);
echo $status_code;
echo "<pre>";
print_r(json_decode($result));
echo "</pre>";
?> ```
````